# Не убирается бэкграунд в первой ячейке ИЕ7

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

```
#menu_item td  { background: url(/i/dotted.png) 0px 50px no-repeat;}
#menu_item td:first-child {background: none;}
```

Не убирается бэкграунд в первой ячейке и только в ИЕ7, подскажите в чём можете быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покажите свою таблицу :)

```
:first-child
```

В Ие7 может работать некорректно, если перед первой td что-то есть. Например комментарий в шаблоне. К примеру тут сработает правило

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>текст</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

а тут нет :)

```
<table>
 <tr>
 <!-- -->
 <td>текст</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

UPD: так же убедитесь, что у вас выставлен правильный doctype. Если он отсутствует и ИЕ7 работает в режиме quirks - он ничего не знает о :first-child

Comment: Да, нашел комментарий. Спасибо!;)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
#menu_item td:first-child {background: none !important;}
```

Может, поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает.